# Prestashop - Error: "install" directory is missing

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to transfer my shop: verpatec.ch/atesum to shop.atesum.com but I got this error: Error: "install" directory is missing.

I've done many transfers like this and I never had problems, it's my first time I see this error.

I checked my settings.inc.php file, and database information is okay.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you tell us how you make this transfer? You just created a sub-domain and moved files here? It was working version? Have you changed DB values (Configuration and ps_shop tables?)

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer"? Do you just want to change its URL? Or completely move it to another host?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing admin folder first?
Usually the admin folder is domain-independent, meaning that you can access it no matter what domain you're on.

In the admin menu, go to `SEO & URLs` and try changing the domain name there. If you have MultiShop, you must change domain for each shop..